# How do I multiply each element in a list with nested lists and get the sum?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a project that goes like this:

```
data = [[0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1]]
res = [4, 2]
```

The objective is to multiply `res` with each element in `data` and get the sum. For example:

```
sum_prod = [[4*(0) + 2*(1)], [4*(1) + 2*(1)], [4*(1) + 2*(0)], [4*(0) + 2*(1)]]
sum_prod = [2, 6, 4, 2] # expected output
```

The code I have looks like this:

```
def fitness_score(g, u):
    a = g
    b = u
    arr = a @ ab
    fitness_value = arr.T.tolist()
    return fitness_value
```

And here is how to call the function `fitness_score`

`fitness_score (data, res)`

This snippet of code that I have works if the data to be called are numpy arrays

The problem is, there are parts in my code which doesn’t accept numpy arrays.

Is there anyway to change the code I have that would readily take lists rather than numpy arrays? So that I could use it all throughout my code?

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`np.multiply`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html), which accepts an [array_like](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.creation.html) as input (and hence lists too) followed by `sum` along the second axis:

```
data = [[0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1]]
res = [4, 2]

np.multiply(data, res).sum(1).tolist()
# [2, 6, 4, 2]
```

Alternatively, and for a more general scenario, you have [`np.asarray`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html), which only creates an array if the input isn't one already, otherwise it returns a view into the input array:

```
def fitness_score(g, u):
    a = np.asarray(g)
    b = np.asarray(u)
    return (a@b).tolist()

fitness_score(data, res)
# [2, 6, 4, 2]
```

Comment: for your first answer, I just want to understand it more since I have the same situation. Does the np.multiply mean that the data and res must be a numpy array before using it which for this case data and res? or can it take variables as type list to and perform the same operation?

Comment: As mentioned, it accepts an `array_like as input (and hence lists too)`. So it works with lists and numpy arrays @acee

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np

data = [[0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1]]
res = [4, 2]

def fitness_score(g, u):
    t = np.array(g)*np.array(u)
    return [sum(n) for n in t]

print(fitness_score(data, res))
```

Output:

```
[2, 6, 4, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a pure python solution, so you won't have to convert back and forth:

```
list(map(sum, (map(lambda x: ([a*b for a, b in zip(x, res)]), data))))
```

```
Out[1]: [2, 6, 4, 2]
```

What it does: for every pair of elements in your longer list, it multiplies every element from the corresponding element in the shorter list, and sums them up. The result in 1 element per element in the long list.

Answer (score 0):

A purer (and even less readable) version of @Nicolas Gervais' answer. No lambda, no comprehension:

```
import operator as op
[*map(sum,zip(*map(map,map(op.attrgetter("__mul__"),res),zip(*data))))]
# [2, 6, 4, 2]
```

Not so much a recommendation. More of a brain teaser for people who enjoy that sort of thing.